I'm failing to run a project with a reference to onnxruntime 1.10/1.16
I'm having a C# / .NET 4.7.2 project, running onnx runtime 1.10 for a long time.
In the last year I started getting errors on some computers. I'm not sure where and why. Last week, it happens almost always.
It DOES work on my computer where I develop, but that's it. Any other computer - fails loading the onnxruntime library:

Failed to load file

I installed it using nuget, and the dll's are in the bin directory.
I take the EXACT bin from my computer, where things work - to the other computer - and it doesn't work.
I managed to install on another computer some test code, having only a single project - and there it works, meaning that other computer has all dependencies installed [VC redist].
PATH is equal on both computers [and I add the path of CUDA\CUDNN] to PATH anyway dynamically...
On that other computer, I tried both, 1.10, and 1.16, and both work with the tester and don't work using the bin I created on my computer [and as mentioned - works on mine]
Any clue? Suggestion?
Example code which works on both computers [and thus isn't very helpful...]
  var ort = OrtEnv.Instance();
  SessionOptions opt = new SessionOptions();

  try
  {
       var opt2 = SessionOptions.MakeSessionOptionWithCudaProvider(0);
       opt = opt2;
  }
  catch (Exception ee)
  {
      hasGPU = false;
      MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
  }

Thanks!

You can get a much more detailed insight into what is happening during assembly resolution using fuslogvw from the Windows SDK

@KlausGütter - Thanks!
I'll give it a try and update

@KlausGütter - thank you so much - using this tool made me understand the bug wasn't there.... some [internal, of mine] artefact of Debug mode made the input be different in DEBUG vs RELEASE... I'll delete the question since it won't be helpful for anybody probably.
